# ggplot2 with more than one line

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, line

I try to create a graph with more than line, i.e. the variables share the same x-axis but differ on the y-axis. I would like to use ggplot2. The problem is that ggplot produces an empty plot without any line. I would like to have 6 lines (V2-V7) plotted against an x-axis going from 1 to 5.

Here is the code of the data for possible reproduction:

```
best_sil <- structure(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "0.9301", "0.93", "0.9286", 
                    "0.9209", "0.8989", "0.9", "0.8064", "0.7947", "0.7607", "0.7451", 
                    "0.8042", "0.7847", "0.7832", "0.7578", "0.7269", "0.7487", "0.7105", 
                    "0.6566", "0.5951", "0.6136", "0.6951", "0.677", "0.6588", "0.5922", 
                    "0.505", "0.6889", "0.6471", "0.6524", "0.5932", "0.5068"), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                         7L))
```

Then I use the function melt(), which normally transforms the dataset in a way that it is usuable for ggplot2 when it comes to plotting more than one line:

```
best_sil2 <- melt(best_sil, id="V1")
```

Another problem that now occurs but didn't before is that melt() produces 5 rows too much (the first five rows are not to be plotted and have no meaning).

And then the ggplot function:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data=best_sil2,
       aes(x=Var1, y=value, colour=Var2)) +
  geom_line()
```

Strangely other quite similar data is working well when I try to plot it (3 lines):

```
test.data.frame <- data.frame(Numb_of_var=c(1,2,3,4,5) ,Group1=c(0.93, 0.92, 0.915, 0.90, 0.892), Group2=c(0.9, 0.88, 0.85, 0.825, 0.75), Group3=c(0.89, 0.85, 0.84, 0.83, 0.72))
test.data.frame2 <- melt(test.data.frame, id="Numb_of_var")
ggplot(data=test.data.frame2,
       aes(x=Numb_of_var, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Your `best_sil` object is not a dataframe, I think this is leading to some of your problems. It is a long character vector. Your `test.data.frame` is actually a dataframe and it has continuous variables, so the figure works.

Comment: You were right! ggplot2 did not accept the data format. I changed the matrix into a data frame and the character vectors into numeric vectors and now the plot works well.